# After removal of a row in a dataframe in pandas. How to handle the missing index?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the below code to remove a row in a dataframe called petrol. By doing this my expected row got removed but its index say 2 also is missing in my dataframe. Do I need to reset the index value or should proceed with my current indexing ?

```
petrol[(petrol_attrib>Lower_Inner_Fence) & (petrol_attrib<Upper_Inner_Fence)]
```

Comment: It very much depends if you need the previous index for sth. or simply want to discard it. `petrol.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)`

Comment: You are not removing any row. You are just filtering on the basis of some conditions

Comment: You don't 'need' to reset the index. In many cases, you actually wouldn't want to reset the index, because once you do, there's no way to reference back to the original `DataFrame`. Many operations like `.shift()` can still work to reference adjacent rows, even if the index is not sequential. And `.iloc[]` will still work to reference the i-th row, regardless of whether the index is `i` or `seventy-six`

Comment: In the case of removing outliers in a dataframe in the case of data analysis, then resetting index is necessary ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine your index as

```
new_df = petrol[(petrol_attrib>Lower_Inner_Fence) & (petrol_attrib<Upper_Inner_Fence)]
new_df.index=range(0,len(petrol)) #you can define your range as required
```

OR

```
new_df = petrol[(petrol_attrib>Lower_Inner_Fence) & (petrol_attrib<Upper_Inner_Fence)].reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True)
```

Comment: Necessarily do we need to do this ? Or we can proceed with certain index values are missing if case of removal of a row in a dataframe.

Comment: You don't need to re-define the index. It is not a necessary step. You can proceed as such

Answer (score 1):

You can using `reset_index()`

```
newdf=petrol[(petrol_attrib>Lower_Inner_Fence) & (petrol_attrib<Upper_Inner_Fence)]
newdf.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
```